# Android Studio project shows no activity and layout

Tags: android

I have just installed Android Studio on my pc, but I am not able to find any activity or layout file on a creation of a new project.
Here is the screen shot
[image: MyProject]

Comment: looks like you havn't created any project as it showing directory path D:\Android workspace try to create new project from this IDE 
File->new->new Project 
see for error logs if occur any

Comment: See: https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/create-project.html

Answer (score 0):

From the screen-shot it is clear that you haven't created any project yet. Go to file - Click on : New - Click on : New Project.

Now create a project which will get you all the necessary elements like activities, layouts, gradle, etc.

Happy coding.